# Detect change of "this" by class itself

Tags: c++

If I have some class with copy/move constructors and operators= defined, can I be sure that my class knows about any change of its "this" pointer? It is needed to be able to notify other classes about changes in "this" pointer. Then other classes will be able to update its pointers and access data inside this class.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

// complex class with support of move semantics
struct Data { int x = 0; };

class A;

// this class often access A::data
// but if A is destroyed it stops doing this
struct B {
        void notify(A* newPointer);
        void access();
        A* pointer = 0;
};

struct A {
        A(B* b) {
                this->b = b;
                if(b) b->notify(this);
        }
        A(A&& a) {
                /* current data will be substituted by new data, 
                 * so object b which depends on it should be 
                 * notified to stop listening */
                if (b) b->notify(0); 

                data = std::move(a.data); // now transfer the data

                b = a.b;

                /* b will know that data is transfered to new class */
                if (b) b->notify(this);

                /* old class will stop notifying b, 
                 * because it doesn't hold the data */
                a.b = 0;
        }
        void operator=(A&& a) {
                if (b) b->notify(0);
                data = std::move(a.data);
                b = a.b;
                if (b) b->notify(this);
                a.b = 0;
        }
        ~A() {
                if (b) b->notify(0);
        }
        B* b = 0;
        Data data;
};

void B::notify (A* newPointer) { pointer = newPointer; }

void B::access () {
        if (pointer) {
                pointer->data.x += 1;
        }
}

int main() {
        B b;
        {
                A a(&b);
                b.access(); // x = 1
                A a2 = std::move(a);
                b.access(); // x = 2
                a = std::move(a2);
                b.access(); // x = 3
                std::cout << a.data.x << std::endl;
        }
        b.access(); // b doing nothing
}
```

Is this implementation 100% robust? Do the constructors and operators= know everything about change of "this"?

---

If you feel that I have chosen wrong wording to explain the problem, I will appreciate suggestions about improvements.

Comment: Do you mean "change to any value in the object" or do you mean "address stored in `this`"? The latter would mean a relocation of the object, probably by being copied around... wouldn't it?

Comment: @Yunnosch I want to detect changes of address stored in `this`. Yes, I want to detect relocations of object by object itself.

Comment: Then please explain how that could happen. Making a [mcve] is probably unavoidable. Show some code which causes a change to the address, then we might understand how to detect it.

Comment: @BhavinChirag That can't happen. A C++ object can't move.

Comment: @molbdnilo OP wants to detect, so lets assume that it does/did happen and lets try to find out what it is that happens and then help detect it. If an MCVE can demonstrate, then I trust the community to come up with a way to detect it. If OP cannot provide an MCVE, then I agree with you.

Comment: @Yunnosch But isn't my example minimal and verifiable? Of course I can miss some cases (so it is not fully complete) that is why I am asking this question.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes it is true, a c++ object can't move. By change of `this`, I mean not to move object itself, but move data inside it and notify about this transfer objects which depend on this data.

Comment: Maybe it is just me not getting it. Would you like to add a few words of explanation or explaining comments? Something like "at this point the object is at a new location and has stopped existing at the old location". If it is just me please accept my apology.

Comment: @BhavinChirag In fact, _trivially copyable_ can be moved, e.g., by `memmove`. In this case, I don't think you can register a change of `this`. But that's not likely what you want anyway.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've added explanation to the move constructor, I think it is the main part where transfer happens. operator= is the same. In `main()` you can see this constructor in action, all `b.access()` change the same data object.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thank you for pointing to this issue. This is what making my implementation fragile.

Comment: @BhavinChirag A live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZyGMAMdiqLYAK51l. Note that this holds only for _trivially copyable_ types, which is not the case of your `A`.

Comment: @plasmacel That's not true, objects technically cannot move in memory (with exceptions). If you exploit move semantics (move constructor), you are not moving any objects. You just create a new object (and optionally "move" some data from the original to the constructed object). The original object remains where it was (in memory) and it is still a valid object that needs to be destructed. Its `this` parameter does not change at all.

Comment: @DanielLangr But isn't my object trivially copyable, because otherwise my implementation will break? I think your example is worth to be an answer.

Comment: @plasmacel After move both objects remain where they were. And the function `std::move` actually does nothing. It is only used to call overload taking an rvalue reference. Note that "move" semantics mean different things in different languages, for example in Rust object could be relocated to a different location after "moved".

Comment: @BhavinChirag `A` is not trivially copyable since it has user-defined move constructor. About the answer, I am not sure whether there are or are not some other ways how to reallocate objects in memory (such as `memmove`). I will try to dig a little bit deeper into this problem.

Comment: Possibly an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If the object is referenced by others, why does it move *at all*? Better approach might be *avoiding* such moving instead of handling it.

Comment: I think this discussion is mostly a terminology problem (since `this` can't change, ever) and what you really want to do is to keep track of which object owns a particular piece of data. I also think this is an idea that would benefit from rethinking.

Comment: @molbdnilo After rethinking I've realized that I am trying to provide `A` and `B` with access to some data object, while lifetimes of `A` and `B` are independent. Maybe holding shared_ptr to the data in `A` and `B` is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: @BhavinChirag That sounds very reasonable to me.